# Can you put multiple types of objects in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have been assigned the task of re-creating the Oregon Trail through java. I have a few requirements - I must have a superclass - `Location` - and sublcasses - `Trail`, `Landmark`, `City`, `Fort`, and `River` and I must use and instantiate them all. I am currently thinking that the best way to approach re-creating the game would be to have a `for` loop (each loop representing one day) and decrement miles to next landmark, execute random chances to be sick, decrement food rations, etc. If I do it this way, the only logical way that I see to differentiate from location to location would be to create an instance of each class for each stop in the game (so Independence would be a city, Kansas River would be a `River`) but my question is, is there a way for me to put all of these instances into one object array even though they are different classes (from the same superclass)? I haven't been able to find any info on the syntax to do this.

Comment: sure, you can, make them implement same interface or declare an array of type `Object[]`

Comment: I think you are looking for Tuples https://github.com/javatuples/javatuples

Comment: `Location[]`, `Location[]`, `Location[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. What you are tying to do is called abstraction, and might be the most powerful feature of polymorphism. **The is-a relationship created by extending the allows to allow us to program for the future, without knowing what the future will bring.**

In your case you can create a `new Location[]` this will instantiate a new array of type `Location`, which will store references to `Location` objects. By definition, since a `Trail` **is-a** `Location`, you will be able to store references to `Trail` objects in a `Location` array. The same applies to all other subclasses of `Location`.

This explains *Hari Lamichhane*:

```
Location[] all = new Location[] {    
new Trail(),
new LandMark(),
new City()
};
```

**However,** the reference to that `new Trail()` object is actually stored as a `Location` reference (that's why you can store that reference in that `new Location[]`. Since Java is *type safe*, without safety casting that reference to a `Trail` reference you will not be able to access any methods not implemented in the super class (`Location`).

Lastly, if the implementation of each type of location is radically different one from the next you may want to consider a *interface* or *abstract class*.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can do that in Java.

As all of your classes are inheriting from `Location` class. You can simply create array like this.

```
Location[] all = new Location[] {
  new Trail(),
  new LandMark(),
  new City()
};
```

Comment: Ok. And I can even do multiple instantiations of each subclass? thanks so much for the quick reply!

Comment: Yes! please mark it as answer if it what you need [its the tick mark in the left side of answer]

Comment: if I were to do the following: 

'Location[] all = new Location[] {
    LandMark chimneyRock = new Landmark(),
   etc...
    }
would that be acceptable syntax?

Comment: `LandMark chimneyRock = new Landmark(); Location[] all = new Location[] { chimneyRock };` you need to add `instance` of the class which is `chimneyRock` in this case.